# Get current data (object/json) from Bootstrap-Treeview

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I am using [Bootstrap-Treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview). I need a tree with checkboxes. And i want to send all tree to the server in treview format when button is pressed. But i can't understand how to extract actual data from treeview.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap-treeview.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var object = [
                {
                    text: "Parent 1",
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            text: "Child 1",
                            nodes: [
                                {
                                    text: "Grandchild 1"
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Child 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: "Parent 2"
                },
            ];

            $('#tree').treeview({
                data: object,
                showCheckbox: true,
            })
                    .on('nodeSelected', function (event, data) {
                        console.log('node selected = ' + JSON.stringify(event) + '; data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                        console.log('object =' + JSON.stringify(object));
                        console.log('tree  =' + JSON.stringify($('#tree').data('treeview')));
                        console.log('tree  2 =' + JSON.stringify($('#tree')));
                        console.log('tree  3 =' + JSON.stringify($('#tree').treeview(true)));
                    });
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tree">twetwe</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After page loads i check any checkbox and than click on any item, so console.log is called. But there is no info about actual state of all treeview. I need that information about all nodes :

```
 {"text":"Child 2","nodeId":3,"parentId":0,"selectable":true,"state":{"checked":false,"disabled":false,"expanded":false,"selected":true}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to get all the nodes of the tree as such because no public method is available on the treeview object that would give the current state of the whole tree .i.e all the nodes.

However it is possible to extract that data indirectly say by combining outputs of treeview.getCollapsed() and treeview.getExpanded() methods into a single object.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap-treeview.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var object = [
                {text: "Parent 1", 
                        nodes: [{text: "Child 1", 
                                    nodes: [{text: "Grandchild 1"}] 
                                }, 
                                {text: "Child 2"} 
                        ] 
                }, 
                {text: "Parent 2"} ];

            $('#tree').treeview({
                data: object,
                showCheckbox: true,
            }).on('nodeSelected', function (event, data) {
                    console.log( getAllNodes() );
                    console.log( JSON.stringify(getAllNodes() ));
                    console.log('node selected = ' + JSON.stringify(event) + '; data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                });
        };

        function getAllNodes(){
            var treeViewObject = $('#tree').data('treeview'),
                allCollapsedNodes = treeViewObject.getCollapsed(),
                allExpandedNodes = treeViewObject.getExpanded(),
                allNodes = allCollapsedNodes.concat(allExpandedNodes);

            return allNodes;
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tree">twetwe</div>`enter code here`
</body>
</html>
```

However please note that the resultant object is not similar in structure to input object that was supplied to treeview as data. Resultant object may be reformatted to construct an object similar to input object.

Comment: Thank you! However, i found that i need checked nodes only. API don't have getChecked method, but in fact it exist.   var checked = $('#tree').treeview('getChecked') - works for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can see all the exposed methods by looking at the 'treeview' object in the console, using:  $('#tree').data('treeview') and then exploring the object.